# What's the inBitmap in Android BitmapFactory.Options class

Tags: android, bitmap

In the episode "`Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently#Managing Bitmap Memory#Manage Memory on Android 3.0 and Higher`" of official training of Android Website, the doc says "If this `inBitmap` option is set, BitmapFactory's decode methods that take the Options object will attempt to reuse an existing bitmap when loading content". Does this sentence mean that the reference of Bitmap has already been transformed into a soft reference?If this, what's the advantage of a soft reference? I think the bitmap object is allocated in equal size whatever the bitmap is a soft ref or a ref of type in `LruCache` .
Please rescue me from this mess.

Comment: read the documentation it already explains that well

Comment: Actually i'v already read the Android Doc, and that's why i asked this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in the documentation for [inBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inBitmap) says anything about soft references.  Java soft references have nothing to do with this flag.  The inBitmap flag is about reusing an existing Bitmap object for decoding a bitmap without having to allocate a new Bitmap object.  Allocating a new Bitmap for decode can be unnecessarily expensive, so you now have the option to reuse a Bitmap when you know it's safe.

Comment: I don't know what did you mean when you said `an existing Bitmap object`.Does that mean i have already had the bitmap reference?If that, why don't me just use this ref instead of decoding a Bitmap another time

Comment: To use inBitmap, you need to have already created a Bitmap object that will fit the image you're trying to decode.  Otherwise, the decoder will create a whole new Bitmap.

Comment: Just like you said, if i have already created a Bitmap object , why don't me just simply use that bitmap object instead of decoding that image again?

Comment: This is for the case when you don't want the contents of the original bitmap and want to replace it with a new image.

Comment: oh,i see.Thanks! 2333333